# how to resolve ,"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, awt

```
    public class queryresult extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    int pos=0;
       String companyvalue;
       String colorvalue;
       String reviewvalue;
        public queryresult() {
            companyvalue=NewJFrame1.query_company;
             colorvalue=NewJFrame1.query_color;
           reviewvalue=NewJFrame1.query_review;
            System.out.println("vaule is coming "+companyvalue);
            System.out.println("Value is "+colorvalue);
            System.out.println("Value is "+reviewvalue);
            initComponents();
            showitem(pos);
        }
        public void getConncetion() 
        {
            Connection conshow=null;
            String userquery="";
            ResultSet showdata=null;

            try
            {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                conshow=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","root");
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(queryresult.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }

        /**
         *
         * @return
         */
        public List<Itemshow> getItemsList()
        {
            Connection conshow=null;
            String userquery="";
            ResultSet showdata=null;

            try
            {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                conshow=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","root");
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(queryresult.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
             PreparedStatement stmt=null;

          List<Itemshow> list=new ArrayList<Itemshow>();
          Itemshow item;
          userquery="select * from RECORDDATA where COMPANY_NM='"+companyvalue+"'and REVIEW= '"+reviewvalue+"'and COLOR_NM= '"+colorvalue+"'";
           try {
                stmt=conshow.prepareStatement(userquery);
                 showdata=stmt.executeQuery();
                while(showdata.next())
                     {
                         item =new Itemshow(showdata.getInt(1),showdata.getString(2),showdata.getString(3),
                                 showdata.getString(4),showdata.getString(5),showdata.getString(6),showdata.getString(7),showdata.getBytes(8));
                         list.add(item);
                     }
                return list;
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(queryresult.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return null;
            }
        }

        public void showitem(int index)
        {
             jTextField_id.setText(Integer.toString(getItemsList().get(index).getId()));
    jTextField_company.setText(getItemsList().get(index).getCompany());
    jTextField_model.setText(getItemsList().get(index).getModel());
    jTextField_style.setText(getItemsList().get(index).getStyle());
    jTextField_color.setText(getItemsList().get(index).getColor());
    jTextField_quality.setText(getItemsList().get(index).getQuality());
    jTextField_review.setText(getItemsList().get(index).getReview());

      ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(getItemsList().get(index).getImage());
              Image image=icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(jLabel2.getWidth(),jLabel2.getHeight(),Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                   jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        }
```

The values of companyvalue,colorvalue,reviewvalue are taken from another frame with choicebox. When user clicks on submit button on frame1 the second frame should come in to picture and shows frame2 with required data (which is read from database).

Above code throws Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. I don't know why? It gives error as

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

```
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at javaapplication1.queryresult.showitem(queryresult.java:156)
at javaapplication1.queryresult.<init>(queryresult.java:50)
at javaapplication1.queryresult$12.run(queryresult.java:490)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stacktrace, not just the exception message.

Comment: As an aside: do yourself and your (future) colleagues a favor, and use a readable and consistent indenting style and/or use an IDE that allows you to apply formatting automatically or at the touch of the right key combo.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  i also uses IDE .(Netbeans)..

Comment: Then I suggest you use its features to make your code look good.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel...yeah...i will definetely do that....thanks you so much.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be query returns zero rows.

Make sure the `getItemsList()` is not empty

Comment: `showdata` is a `ResultSet`, and indexes in result sets are 1-based